# How to track which rows in a dataframe have NA values in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, rows, na

I'm working now with some really big dataframes and in order to shorten the calculations I need to exclude rows with NA values, but after the calculation and creating new dataframe I need to bring them back (to the new dataframe). Is there any possibility to track which rows I exclude?

for example:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4
1  3  4  5  4
2  3  3  3  4
3  NA NA NA NA
4  4  3  3  2
```

So what I want is to get after "complete.cases" number 3, that refers to the row number with NA that was excluded. Is it possible without adding extra column with numbering?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have tried anything yourself?

Comment: check `?complete.cases`

Comment: @Emkin Welcome here at SO. Please help us to create a quick and accurate answer by including example data in R (e. g. generated via `dput` or `read.table` with `text=` parameter), the expected result (data) and the code you have tried so far. Thanks!

Comment: @Emkin Please read a litte bit about subsetting. There is no need to duplicate or remove data just for calculation purposes. In case of "big dataframes" (how big) this is even more important. Have a look at the package "data.table" and read the doc. `data.table` is a high performance replacement for `data.frame` but has a different syntax if you want to really improve the performance.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `na.omit`, then `attr(na.omit(df), "na.action")` gives 3.

Also,

```
rownames(df)[!complete.cases(df)]
# [1] "3"
```

Comment: As a variation, I would suggest `has_na <- which(!complete.cases(df))`

Answer (score 1):

To return the indices of rows containing at least one `NA` we could also use:

```
rownames(df[rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0,])
# [1] "3"
```